# Adding individual arrows in multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add arrows in 2 plots produced with ggplot and faceting. Problem: how can I avoid a replication of the arrow in both graphs? I would like to add individual arrows to each plot.
Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
# data frame with fake data
xdf <- data.frame(x=rep(1:10,2)
                  ,y=c( 2*c(1:10)+rnorm(10,0,3), 4*c(1:10)+rnorm(10,0,5))
                  ,z=rep(c("A","B"),each=10)
                  )
xdf

# ggplot with faceting
   xp <- ggplot(xdf,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
       geom_line() +
       facet_grid(. ~ z)
   xp

# location of the arrow: x=4, y= on the top

(f1x4 <- xdf[4,"y"])+1
xp + geom_segment(aes(x=4,xend=4,y=f1x4+3,yend=f1x4)
                      , arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.4,"cm")
                        )
                     ) +
      geom_text(aes(x=4,y=f1x4+5, label="a"))
```

What happened:
arrow is placed in both facets in the identical region. How can I choose a specific plot to place the arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, to add individual layers onto a facet, you need to supply a data frame with the corresponding facet value.

From the [ggplot2 facet_grid page](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html):

```
# If you combine a facetted dataset with a dataset that lacks those 
# facetting variables, the data will be repeated across the missing 
# combinations:
```

So just doing `xp + geom_segment(aes(x,xend,y,yend))` will draw on all facets, because the facetting variable is missing.

Your facetting variable is `z`, so you can either:

- create a dataframe `arrow.df` with `x`, `y`, and `z` being 'A'
- feed the `z` into `aes` directly.

Second option seems handier:

```
xp + geom_segment(aes(x=4,xend=4,y=f1x4+3,yend=f1x4,z='A')  # <-- see the z='A'
                      , arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.4,"cm")
                        )
                     ) +
      geom_text(aes(x=4,y=f1x4+5, label="a",z='A'))         # <-- see the z='A'
```

So you just add in a `factorvariablename=factor` to the `aes` argument to plot on that particular panel (since your `z` column in the data frame for `xp` has levels 'A' and 'B').

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I want and it is somehow embarassing how simple the solution is.