# Arrowhead used as a size aesthetic in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got data containing vectors' coordinates and their characteristics - `success_rate` and `prop`:

```
ex_data <- structure(list(group = c("group A", "group A", "group A", "group A", 
"group A", "group A", "group C", "group C", "group C", "group C", 
"group C", "group W", "group W", "group W", "group W", "group W"
), category = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2, 
3), success_rate = c(0.816037735849057, 0.938775510204082, 0.653061224489796, 
0.985915492957746, 0.934306569343066, 1, 0.979166666666667, 0.887323943661972, 
0.319587628865979, 0.721590909090909, 0.941176470588235, 0.689320388349515, 
0.338028169014085, 0.396551724137931, 0.7375, 0.763948497854077
), x0 = c(24.5, 24.5, 23.7, 22.6, 28.6, 27.6, 27.2, 27.4, 15.7, 
25.5, 24.2, 21.4, 17.5, 9.9, 23.6, 29), y0 = c(21.2, 27.9, 96.6, 
43.9, 65.1, 71.5, 34.3, 71.2, 47.9, 88, 36, 86.9, 49.4, 41.3, 
85.6, 16.7), x1 = c(35.2, 36.5, 34, 32.9, 39.4, 40.2, 35.9, 31.6, 
63.1, 29.5, 35.9, 35.4, 61.4, 54, 37.3, 37.2), y1 = c(5.8, 33.6, 
96.8, 70, 64.8, 96.6, 7.3, 64.9, 63.1, 89.7, 38.5, 95, 59.3, 
32.2, 77.9, 12), prop = c(0.124926340601061, 0.0866234531526223, 
0.0288744843842074, 0.041838538597525, 0.0807307012374779, 0.0271066588096641, 
0.0365853658536585, 0.0541158536585366, 0.0739329268292683, 0.134146341463415, 
0.0259146341463415, 0.0787461773700306, 0.108562691131498, 0.0443425076452599, 
0.0611620795107034, 0.178134556574924)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

I wan't to make a graphic of vectors for each `group` that would use `prop` as a size aesthetic. Unfortunetely, I don't think in case of arrows size aesthetics doesn't work well as its resizing the whole arrow which often look bad:

```
ggplot(ex_data) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x0, y = y0, xend = x1, yend = y1, color = success_rate, size = prop),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm"), ends = 'last', type = 'closed')) +
  facet_wrap(~group) +
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]

So I would like to control only the size of the arrowhead with `prop` variable. Unfortunetely, arrowheads are not `geom_segment` aesthetic and the only way to control their sizes is to supply them with separate vector. It works nice for a single group:

```
ex_data %>% 
  filter(group == 'group C') %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x0, y = y0, xend = x1, yend = y1, color = success_rate),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(filter(ex_data, group == 'group C')$prop * 3, "cm"), ends = 'last', type = 'closed')) +
  facet_wrap(~group) +
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]

but not with `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(ex_data) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x0, y = y0, xend = x1, yend = y1, color = success_rate),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(ex_data$prop * 3, "cm"), ends = 'last', type = 'closed')) +
  facet_wrap(~group) +
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]

You can notice that sizes of arrowheads for `group C` are not valid anymore (eg. the upper arrow should have the biggest arrowhead, while it has the smallest). My original data has much more groups and creating separate plots would be really tedious. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is usual in such cases (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9473015/1320535), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11889625/1320535), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14508277/1320535)), we may use sub-data frames for each facet. For instance,

```
ggplot(ex_data) +
  lapply(split(ex_data, ex_data$group), function(df)
  geom_segment(data = df, aes(x = x0, y = y0, xend = x1, yend = y1, color = success_rate),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(df$prop * 3, "cm"), ends = 'last', type = 'closed'))) +
  facet_wrap(~group) + scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]